# Problem with converting Integral to Gamma functions (from HQET heavy quark self-energy diagram)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, dimensional-regularization, self-energy

In the calculation of HQET radiative correction, I came across the Equation:
$$\int_0^{\infty}d\lambda ~ \lambda^{-\epsilon}(\lambda+\omega)^{-\epsilon} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\epsilon-\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(1-\epsilon)(-\omega)^{1-2\epsilon},$$ where $\epsilon =2-\frac{d}{2}$ is the usual DREG regulator and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$. I have no idea how to proof this equality. My guess is that one has to use something like $$\int_0^{\infty}dx ~e^{-\lambda x^2 }= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4\lambda}},$$ which gets the exponential for the Gamma function and the factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$. But I can't figure out how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can resort to the Beta and Gamma function and their properties to sort this out. I find a slightly different result, with distinct powers of $2$, but it might still help.

In addition, I will assume that $\omega > 0$ so I'll get some some signs differently but you can directly extend the result for $\omega < 0$ with the proper sign changes (I believe the latter is probably the choice of your result).

With $\omega > 0$, I make the change of variables $u = \frac{\lambda}{\omega}$ to find
\begin{eqnarray}
\int^{\infty}_{0} \, \frac{1}{\lambda^\epsilon \, \left(\lambda + \omega \right)^\epsilon} \, \mathrm{d} \lambda &=& \frac{1}{\omega^{2\epsilon - 1}} \, \int^{\infty}_{0} \, \frac{u^{-\epsilon}}{\left(1+u\right)^\epsilon} \, \mathrm{d} u \, = \, \frac{1}{\omega^{2\epsilon - 1}} \, \mathrm{B} \left(1-\epsilon,2\epsilon-1 \right)
\\
&=& \frac{1}{\omega^{2\epsilon - 1}} \, \Gamma\left(1-\epsilon\right) \, \frac{\Gamma\left(2\epsilon-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\epsilon\right)} \, = \, \frac{1}{\omega^{2\epsilon - 1}} \, \Gamma\left(1-\epsilon\right) \, \frac{\Gamma\left(\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2^{2\left(1-\epsilon\right)} \, \sqrt{\pi}} \, ,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mathrm{B}\left(x,y\right)$ is the Beta function and $\Gamma(z)$ is the Gamma function. You can find the properties I used in the corresponding wikis.